# Безопасно ли выводить так текст? (И правильное использование GET/POST/REQUEST)

Tags: php, безопасность

Скажите пожалуйста, безопасна ли такая конструкция?

```
<?php
$search = $_GET['search'];
echo htmlspecialchars($search);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Смотря что вы понимаете под безопасностью. JS в браузере у клиента не запустится. Если там потом какой-нибудь другой злой скрипт не отработает :-) Это безопасно *тактически*.
2. **Никогда** не используйте сырой $_GET. Это  плохой тон, дурно пахнет и трудно кодится, трудно ищется.
3. Это **небезопасно** *стратегически* : обращение к $_GET идет в обход любой валидации, следовательно, привыкнув использовать $_GET, когда-нибудь вы возьмете инпут пользователя, попытаетесь записать его в базу данных и вашему сайту придет ...
4. Если это в API какого-то твоего (даже внутреннего) сервиса и ты выдаешь так ответ где-нибудь далее по коду, то, насколько я понимаю символы `'`, `-` (`--` sql-коммент)  `;` не будут экранироваться, они не являются специальными символами для html, насколько я помню.  Клиент апи может словить что-нибудь вроде DROP DATABASE SOME_BASE;
5. Это небезопасно с точки зрения поддержки кода. Из *рабочей практики*: представьте себе функцию, которая принимает на вход какие-нибудь параметры, время от времени она обращается к $_GET  и производит с ним какие-нибудь манипуляции. Логично предположить, что код такой функции представляет собой лапшу. Пока кто-нибудь не сделает рефакторинг, код будет становиться все лапшеобразней.

   - Допустим, кодер, который делает какую-нибудь задачу, потратив время на рефакторинг/попытки понять как функция работает, устанет и допустит баг, который может и не приведет к прямым потерям (не спишет весь баланс пользователя), но приведет к даунтайму. Даунтайм = деньги. Уязвимость = деньги. Следовательно, уязвимость = даунтайм. Плохой код = даунтайм = деньги = уязвимость. Плюс потери рабочего времени (*денег*) на починку багов.

Для начала, если вы **из принципа** или **на период обучения** не хотите использовать фреймворки, сделайте хотя бы сырую функцию-обертку  типа

```
    class http{
    // это не образец хорошего кода, тут нехватает документации
    // это просто пример для людей, которые не используют фреймворки
    // php позволяет указывать значения аргументов по умолчанию, поэтому
    // функцию можно вызывать без аргументов, с одним или двумя аргументами
    // php allows to set default arguments for a function
    // ( php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

    public static function get($name=false, $default=null){
        if (!empty($_POST)){
            $_GET=$_POST; //lazy, dangerous, bad code. 
        }

        if (!$name){
            return $_GET; // do what you want with get
        }

        if (!isset($_GET[$name])){
            return $default; // return null or default value
            // or throw an exception
        }else{
            return $_GET[$name]; // return value
        }
      }
    }
```

используешь, например как `$search = http::get("search")`;  если будешь бросать эксепшен не придется проверять `if ($search === null)`

(код старый, поэтому класс вместо неймспейса, get/post манипуляции из-за того, что это in-house проект для внутренней админки)

плюс такого подхода (это называется *инкапсуляция*):

- всегда можешь найти **в своем коде** обращение к `$_GET`,
- всегда можешь вставить туда дебаг.
- тебе не придется проверять в тысяче мест существование индекса массива  в $_GET
- IDE типа PhpStorm будет понимать, что это вызов функции с параметрами.
- в дальнейшем, переезжая на фреймворк или делая тяжелый рефакторинг, ты всегда сможешь или найти эти вызовы и избавиться от них или внедрить их в чужой код без особых потерь по скорости

если вы не хотите использовать фреймворки или компоненты - путь вам в конструирование велосипеда, но и велосипеды полезны для обучения.

так-то - сейчас работу с http принято вести через `google://Guzzle` и в принципе всю работу с php через `google://composer+php`

Comment: Лично моё мнение, что применив вашу реализацию функции `get($name=false, $default=null)` в конечном итоге **ничего** не изменится, в переменной окажется та же строка. Только появляется  новая обёртка. `if (!empty($_POST)) $_GET=$_POST;` это странно выглядит) Не проще ли взять сразу из `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: тут ты прав, но (насколько я помню), это разделение я сделал как раз для того, чтобы не забывать, про get/post. а так да, если принять функцию как данность, то лучше на $_REQUEST сменить. Основной цимес там в том, чтобы не проверять на isset, в итоге в переменной окажется или значение http-параметра или null (или можно бросить эксепшн) Просто я очень часто встречал в коде проверки на существование параметра в http-запросе, это... бесит. И да, второй цимес в том, чтобы $_GET обрабатывался системно и в одной точке входа, а не по всему коду

Comment: Что вообще значит этот код? `$name=false, $default=null` Вы присваиваете переменным значения, но потом проверяете не пустые ли они.

Comment: это дефолтные значения аргументов  для функции.  http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php По умолчанию (при вызове функции без аргументов они будут false/null) в дальнейшем можно вызывать функцию без аргументов, с одним или с двумя аргументами

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно безопасна.

Не подвержена XSS и sql-инъекциям))

Comment: кстати, если у него API, который получает данные по http, обращаясь к этому коду и записывая результат в БД, то ' и ; не проэкранируются

Comment: @strangeqargo Не проэкранируются. Вопрос то не про запись в БД, а про безопасный вывод текста. Перед записью в БД переменные само собой экранировать нужно.

Comment: я имею ввиду, что щас часто делают "микросервисы" со всякими rest и т.д. Т.е. можно пробросить drop database сквозь валидацию, если гет приходит от пользователя, а потом какой-то другой сервис пытается это уложить в sql бд. Могу соврать, но, кажется, я где-то читал как где-то такая ботва пробрасывалась через логи

Comment: @strangeqargo Может быть, я ошибаюсь, но, мне кажется, что вы слегка надумываете проблемы)) Может в рамблере знают больше чем я)) Брать из $_GET вполне безопасно. Как мне кажется, работать лучше с чистой переменной, а при выводе/вставках в БД проделывать необходимые манипуляции. Собственно `htmlspecialchars` при вставках в БД нет вообще смысла делать, это даже попортит исходные данные. А при выводе на экран как раз есть смысл, чтобы теги из текста не интерпретировались браузером как теги.

Comment: при выводе на экран - да. я поэтому и написал, что тактически - ок. Но чисто с точки зрения стратегической безопасности и поддержки кода - это чудовищно. И очень неудобно. Представь, ты разбил код на функции. И тут вдруг у тебя функция, которая, игнорируя все манипуляции, забирает входящий параметр из $_GET (он же глобальный, доступен всем) и ты дебажишь эту дрянь. А потом начинаешь ненавидеть программиста, который это написал. А если кодер - злой дебил и вставил `if ($_GET['vasya']) {giveAllMoneyToVasya();}` ? P.S. рамблер или нет неважно, но легаси-код и его объемы дают нюх на проблемы :-)

Comment: а так ты взял переменную, провалидировал ее в своей domain-области и знаешь, что никто больше нигде по коду не будет творить чудес c изменением $_GET. это успокаивает, ну, ты ведь сам знаешь, почему фреймворки пишут. Олсо, оффтопом, извини за разговор на "ты", но я не люблю "вы" в русском языке и стараюсь его не использовать, имхо, это пережиток рабского прошлого

Comment: @strangeqargo Я понял о чем вы) Ну да, в этом есть резон.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40567/discussion-between-jekaby-and-strangeqargo).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40591/discussion-between-jekaby-and-strangeqargo).